# Custom made PCB problem after lost power supply

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, stm32, flash, bootloader

I have 2 custom PCB which need to communicate via Spi. Communication works fine when I flash code and MCUs have stable power supply. After disconnecting from power supply and then reconnecting slave MCU send some garbage and I need to press reset button on PCB to allow normal operation to continue, basically after pressing reset button on slave everything works fine. I read that wrong connection on BOOT0 and RST pins can make such mistakes. On logic analyzer I see that I have some glitch on BOOT0, glitch intervals are not periodic and take a little time. I figure out one more thing, when MCU don't have power supply and I press reset button and hold that button and then connect power supply to MCU and then release button I got fine result, communication works good.

Any idea is welcome.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is captured start sequence when PCB is connected to power supply.

[image]

Comment: How's your low voltage detect configured?

Comment: Be advised that a cheap logic analyzer probes sometimes introduce the noise themselves. They can be coupling signals from the other channels. I've seen this break communication using a cheap Saleae clone.

Comment: @Lundin I don't configurate logic levels, I use default setup.

Comment: @akwky Thanks but I figure out that, without logic analyzer result is same. I use uart for debug. That how I know that spi send garbage when there is no logic analyzer in conncetion with PCB.

Comment: @subavet995 And the default is what? Enabled? Disabled? 2.7V? Something else?

Comment: Can you specify part family and operating conditions?

Comment: @Lundin 3.2V on 3v3 and 3.1V on RST pin

Comment: @Jeroen3 stm32f405vgt and stm32f401ceu. Operation condition? Master initiate communication with slave via SS low level, after finishing communication master pull up SS line. On slave side spi communication is realized in next way: trigger(call spi function) on low level on SS line.

Comment: Not function, I meant temperature and Vdd.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Look above for voltage. I test on room temperature

Comment: The noise on the boot0 coincident with SPI operations is highly suspicious.  Do you have a common ground between your analyzer and the device under test?   Use an order of magnitude smaller pulldown resistor.  Inspect the board under 10x magnification and look for pin-pin shorts.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes logic analyzer gnd is connected to PCB gnd, I try to test boot0 on other lines of logic analyzer and result is same. I found what cause problem, look my answer. My dilema is now why I got random glitch on boot0, I will try to think more and I will write answer if I conclude what cause glitch.

Comment: @subavet995 "3.2V on 3v3 and 3.1V on RST pin"  That doesn't sound right. If the LVD kicks in as far up as 3.2V, it would be unstable like anything. That rather sounds like the correct limit to use for 5V supply.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the 100k on BOOT0 is not pull-down enough. In the newer F4 series the BOOT0 pin also serves high voltage programming supply (Vpp).

On the demo boards they hard tie BOOT0 to ground without pull-down, or use a 10k resistor.

Maybe you can measure the leakage from BOOT0 to determine the highest possible resistor.

Answer (score 0):

I found what is problem. Problem is cheap logic analyzer and cables for communication. Small raster is used (raster 1) + bad connection on cables + logic analyzer = unpredictable behavior. Thanks all for help

Comment: In case you need more info on Answering Your Own Question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: This is unlikely to be the actual problem, at least not on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the right solution, but you can try to connect slave's reset to master and detect it being plugged in.
Let there be 2 lines connecting Master and Slave other than SPI:

One of the lines is Slave's reset.
Second line is master's input pulled down on the master side and connects to Slave's VCC

When slave is plugged in, the Second line (let's call it SLAVESNS) goes high. Master either polls it occasionally or gets an interrupt. Then master waits a pair of millliseconds and pulls slave's reset low and back high.

There may be other ways to make reset happen using small circuits of course, maybe even without interrupt, just analog circuit, but I still find it reasonable to have slave's reset being controlled by the master, maybe you even make reset low by default and only when you detect something connected you let it go high

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense or have much to do with the question